# checking dynamically named selects using jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

How can I use jquery to get the value of a dynamically named select?

I have several (no exact number) of selects that populated like this:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($manifest); $i++)
        echo '<select id="headerColumn_' . $i . '">
            <option value="">-- Column Header --</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        </select>';
    ?>
```

Later on, i have a button that includes an onclick to a function.  When that function is called, I pass how many selects were created.  Now, I need to get the value of all the selects.  I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < valuePassedIntoFunction; i++)
{
    var thisValue = $("#headerColumn_" + i).val();
    alert("#headerColumn_" + i + " = " + thisValue);
}
```

but when I run the page, i just a popup with this:

```
#headerColumn_1 = undefined
```

How can i get jquery to accept my dynamic naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `$.map` function to iterate over all elements with an ID starting with `headerColumn_`, and return each elements value into an array :

```
var arr = $.map($('[id^="headerColumn_"]'), function(el, i) {return el.value; });
```

or to alert all the ID's and values:

```
$('[id^="headerColumn_"]').each(function(i, el) {
    alert(el.id + ' = ' + el.value);
});
```

Comment: Should I run one of these two from inside the for loop?  If not, where's the "i" variable coming from?  I tried it from inside the for loop and nothing happened - i.e. no alerts were triggers displaying information.

Comment: Nope, not inside the loop, just inside document ready should do ?

Comment: then what's the i variable in function(el, i)?  Also, trying it outside of the for loop results in the same thing... nothing